# Several test pass in intellij but fails in cmd

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, junit

So I have several tests that pass in IntelliJ but fails when I run them in cmd.

Is there a way to refresh IntelliJ settings that could cause false test results?

PS. Tests are not related to files or any location - I found it as a reason in one post.

Comment: No, IntelliJ knows how to run those tests.  Look at the error messages - it's something that you did differently in the command shell.

Comment: You should show the code and the error because otherwise we could not help you.

Comment: Be aware that the test support in IntelliJ by default do things slightly different to speed up things, which may result in especially static variables not being reset properly between tests.  Also the order tests are executed in may change too.  These things can be tweaked inside Intellij.  Before doing that I would suggest you create a minimal example showing the behavior you see which you can share.

Comment: How did you run your tests from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

at the begining of your test launched by UntelliJ, you can see the parameters used by intelliji, and compare with your cmd